# Improper rendering at axes border in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, wxpython, rendering

I want to render a rectangle within an axes in matplotlib.  The axes is the unit square with the origin at the bottom left corner.  For the case where the rectangle is the same size as the axes - I want the rectangle to appear as though it is the border of the axes.

The problem is that it appears that the rendering is incorrect.  The left (x=0) and top (y=1) of the rectangle get rendered, but the bottom (y=0), and right (x=1) do not show up.

Note: This is not specific to only rectangles ... it remains true for lines as well.  The resulting rendering appears as:

[image: Improper rectangle rendering.]

The following code snippet demonstrates the problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

r = mpl.Rectangle((0,0), 1, 1, edgecolor='red', facecolor='none', zorder=100)

axes = mpl.gca()
axes.add_patch(r)
axes.set_xbound(0, 1)
axes.set_ybound(0, 1)

axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

[spine.set_visible(False) for spine in axes.spines.values()]

mpl.show()
```

I have also rendered to PDF and verified that this works correctly (for example when zooming in all sides are present).

This seemingly has to do with how the underlying image gets rasterized to the screen. Is there a way around this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact behavior is backend dependent (Your example works as you'd like it to on my system.)

However, if you turn clipping off for your rectangle, it should behave as you want on any backend.

In your example above, just do `r.set_clip_on(False)`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = plt.Rectangle((0,0), 1, 1, edgecolor='red', facecolor='none', zorder=100)

ax = plt.gca()
ax.add_patch(r)
ax.axis([0, 1, 0, 1])

ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)

[spine.set_visible(False) for spine in ax.spines.values()]

r.set_clip_on(False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joe.  Your solution makes sense and fixes my problem.  But this does beg two other questions. Is this a bug in my back_end?  Seems to be.  Second, what is the difference with clipping on or off?  Is clipping off a little less efficient for drawing? I only ask because I am doing a lot of animating.

Comment: @Rocketman - I'm not sure if it's a bug. You could ask on the users list, and probably get a much better answer than I could give you. As for the second:  I don't think (??) that clipping will affect the speed of animations too much in simple cases.  (Use blitting if you're not already. There are a couple of tutorials on it on the matplotlib page.)